# How to convert varchar to time stamp in DB2

Tags: date, datetime, db2

I'm trying to convert a column with data type varchar to time stamp in DB2.

Eg: column has a value '1.12.1999 00:00:00' which is a varchar

My code is `date(to_date(column_name,'DD.MM.YYYY HH:MI:SS'))`

I'm getting the following error:

"1.12.1999 00:00:00" cannot be interpreted using format string "DD.MM.YYYY HH:MI:SS" for the TIMESTAMP_FORMAT function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error is that the time portion "00:00:00" is not valid. Try using `date(to_date(column_name,'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))`. [The HH24 allows "00" as hour.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007107.html)